# Reverting use of useEffect in flutter_hooks

Tags: flutter, hook, riverpod

I'm migrating existing project handed by another vendor, which in this case, using `flutter_hooks` in it. I am nothing against using hooks or other dependencies, just personal preference, I'd say.

I found some usages are easy to convert back without hooks, like `useState`, `useValueChanged` etc.

But, I have a problem with `useEffect`, especially with stream keys filled.

If I have

```dart
useEffect(() {
  // do something
  return null;
}, []);
```

I could easily turn it into `initState` for `// do something` and `return () {}` for `dispose` function. CMIIW.

but I saw in this project that `useEffect` also could listen non-stream variables in keys, like this one

```dart
useEffect(() {
  // do something
  return null;
}, [nonStream, propsFromRiverpodState]);
```

For now I use temporary variables to detect if variables are changed/different than before, but is there any real solution to this?

Comment: That's pretty much what it's doing.  If the list of keys changes, the effect re-runs.  Everything hooks does, you can do with a stateful widget.  It just takes a lot more coding.  Why are you removing hooks if they are working fine?

Comment: Unfortunately, the app is not doing fine with it, it's not because of the hooks but the implementation is not what we're comfortable with and found some paterns for example passing `useState`'s ValueNotifier instead of callback like that. just preference.